# Retag [git]+[submodule] into [git-submodules]

Tags: support, retag-request

[65 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git+submodule) about Git submodules are tagged [git](/questions/tagged/git)  [submodule](/questions/tagged/submodule), while [git-submodules](/questions/tagged/git-submodules) is also used (100 questions). [submodule](/questions/tagged/submodule) can also refer to python submodules, maybe this could be another retag request, so a tag synonym is inappropriate